# Bit swapping probability question

Tags: probability, limits, bit-strings

> Let $x = x(1), \dots , x(n)$ be a bit string containing exactly $m$ occurrences of 1. Consider the following operation on $x$: we choose a random pair of indices $(i,j),$ and we swap $x(i)$ and $x(j)$ so that $x'(i) = x(j),$ $x'(j) = x(i),$ while $x'(k) = x(k)$ if $k \neq i$ and $k \neq j.$ (If $i = j,$ therefore, then we change nothing.) Let $X_1 = x,$ and let $X_2, \dots, X_N$ be obtained by such a sequence of operations (always swapping a new random pair) that so $X_{r+1} = X_r$. The number of 1s remains $m$ in each iteration. Show for each $i$, we have $P(X_N (i) = 1) \rightarrow \frac{m}{n}$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

What's confusing me is that it seems as though the probability on any iteration of $X_j$ that $X_j(i) = 1$ is always $\frac{m}{n}$, which would make the problem trivial.

Comment: I think the initial bit string $x$ is meant to be non-random, so $P(X_0(i)=1)$ is either $0$ or $1$, depending on $x(i)$.

Comment: Even if that's true for $X_0$, why wouldn't it be the case that on $P(X_1(i)=1) = \frac{m}{n}$ considering there are $m$ 1s and $n$ choices?

Comment: Suppose $x(1)=0$.  For $X_1(1)=1$ to happen, one of the  initial swap locations $i$ or $j$ must equal to $1$; this happens with probability $1-(1-1/n)^2$, which is small if $n$ is big.  Note: from $N$ to $N+1$ at most 2 of the entries in the $x$ array change, leaving at least $n-2$ unchanged.

Comment: One of the initial swap locations $i$ or $j$ must be equal to one, but also, if $i = 1$, then wouldn't $X(j) = 1$ also have to be true, which would change your probability?

Comment: You are right: for $x(1)$ to change two things must happen: $1$ must be a swapped location, *and* what it swaps with must be different.  This means change is even rarer than what I wrote, which is now even smaller than your guess $P(X_1(i_=1)=m/n$.

Comment: *"$X_{r+1} = X_r$"* $\quad$What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that given any $1\leq i \leq n$, there exists a steady equilibrium state, with equilibrium probability $P(X_{i}=1,t)=\frac{m}{n}, P(X_{i}=0,t)=1-\frac{m}{n}$ for all time $t\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$, t>T for some $T$.

At time $t+1$, we have

$P(X_{i}=1,t+1)=P(X_{i}=1,t)(P(\text{switch $i$ with another filled site}))+P(X_{i}=1,t)(P(\text{site $i$ is left untouched at the 't+1'th time}))+P(X_{i}=0,t)(P(\text{switch $i$ with a filled site}))$

Thus, $P(X_{i}=1,t+1)=(\frac{m}{n})\frac{m-1}{{n}\choose{2}}+(\frac{m}{n})\frac{{n-1}\choose{2}}{{n}\choose{2}}+(1-\frac{m}{n})\frac{m}{{n}\choose{2}}=\frac{m}{n}$. A similar calculation shows that $P(X_{i}=0,t+1)=(1-\frac{m}{n})$; i.e the probabilites add up to $1$, at time $t+1$.

It seems the system is such that given any initial configuration, you may be able to get to this equilibrium state; but I've not worked that out explicitly.